# Global Variables, Functions and Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Apologies for what I assume is such a basic question, but a cursory google search of javascript functions returns all sorts of stuff about 'this' and why not to declare things globally, and creating objects -- all of which is way over my head.

I am trying to make an interactive geochart using [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization). I have a working version here (sort of):

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geochart']});

    var width, height, selectedRegion, resolution;

    window.onload = function(){
      width = 556;
      height = 400;
      selectedRegion = 'world';
      resolution = 'subcontinents';
    };

    function drawVisualization() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Region');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
      data.addRows([
        [{v:"005", f:"South America"}, 978.7],
        [{v:"011", f:"Western Africa"}, 46],
        [{v:"013", f:"Central America"}, 299],
        [{v:"014", f:"Eastern Africa"}, 63.9],
        [{v:"015", f:"Northern Africa"}, 255.7],
        [{v:"017", f:"Middle Africa"}, 21.4],
        [{v:"018", f:"Southern Africa"}, 244.5],
        [{v:"029", f:"Caribbean"}, 76.5],
        [{v:"030", f:"Eastern Asia"}, 5712.9],
        [{v:"034", f:"Southern Asia"}, 1275.1],
        [{v:"035", f:"South-Eastern Asia"}, 639.2],
        [{v:"039", f:"Southern Europe"}, 777.8],
        [{v:"053", f:"Australia and New Zealand"}, 272],
        [{v:"054", f:"Melanesia"}, 6.3],
        [{v:"057", f:"Micronesia"}, 1.8],
        [{v:"061", f:"Polynesia"}, 1],
        [{v:"143", f:"Central Asia"}, 170.3],
        [{v:"145", f:"Western Asia"}, 834.1],
        [{v:"151", f:"Eastern Europe"}, 1587.6],
        [{v:"154", f:"Northern Europe"}, 801.5],
        [{v:"155", f:"Western Europe"}, 1456.2],
        [{v:"021", f:"Northern America"}, 4704.1]
      ]);

      var options = {
        displayMode: 'regions',
        enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
        resolution: resolution,
        region: selectedRegion,
        height: height,
        width: width
      };

      var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
          document.getElementById('visualization'));

      google.visualization.events.addListener(geochart, 'select', function() {
        var selection = geochart.getSelection();

        if (selection.length == 1) {
          var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
          selectedRegion = data.getValue(selectedRow, 0);
          resolution = "countries";
          options.region = selectedRegion;
          options.resolution = resolution;
          //alert(resolution);
          geochart.draw(data, options);
          }
      });

      geochart.draw(data, options);
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What the code does properly (and what I want to refine as part of a bigger project) is that when you click a region on the map, it will change the options of the map and redraw it, to zoom in further on that region.

This is splendid, but the above is one massive function, with a handler function inside a function. This would get quite unwieldy since I have to add things like zooming out, and resetting the map to look at the whole world, and also have to adjust a much larger data set according to what region is selected (the above example will zoom in on a region and then show no data currently).

So I want to break my code in to more manageable chunks, chunks which can be debugged individually, give me a better sense of what's going wrong where, and generally make the entire project more manageable on my end since I am far from an expert programmer (probably far from a novice programmer to be honest).

Here are the chunks I want to break it in to:

1. define data (every time options are changed)
2. define options (every time options are changed)
3. draw map (every time functions 5-7 are executed)
4. add listener (once)
5. function to zoom in on map (on click)
6. function to zoom out on map (on click)
7. function to reset map (on click)
8. function to manipulate data (every time functions 5-7 are executed)

Where I run in to problems is in the very basic stuff. I can declare all my variables globally (without prefixing them with `var`) but I think this is generally discouraged, and probably will hurt me long run (especially if I have a giant data table that is declared variably with 10,000 elements). *If this is wrong, please correct me -- using global variables from my limited understanding is a bad thing, but maybe javascript is special?*

Let's focus on one of these functions, and then if I understand how that one function works and interacts, then I can probably figure out the other ones.

To draw a chart, I need to have two pieces of information:

1. What data to use
2. What options to use

Now if I declare both data and options as global variables, I can happily manipulate them from other functions (thank you very much), but they are global. I can't figure out how to pass the things in to a function, and return the adjusted data as needed.

For instance, I can easily create a working map as follows:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var rawData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  rawData.addColumn('string','Continent');
  rawData.addColumn('string','Subontinent');
  rawData.addColumn('string','Country');
  rawData.addColumn('number','Data');
  rawData.addRows([
    [{v:"142",f:"Asia"},{v:"145",f:"Western Asia"},{v:"AE",f:"United Arab Emirates"},91.9],
    // more data in between
    [{v:"002",f:"Africa"},{v:"014",f:"Eastern Africa"},{v:"ZW",f:"Zimbabwe"},7.8],
  ]);

  resetMap();

  var data = new google.visualization.DataView(rawData);
  data.setColumns([resolutionIndex, 3]);

  var options = {
    displayMode: displayMode,
    enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
    resolution: resolution,
    region: region,
    height: height,
    width: width
  };

  drawMap(data, options);

}

function drawMap(data, options) {
  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, options);
}

function resetMap() {
  resolutionArray = ['continents', 'subcontinents', 'countries'];
  resolutionIndex = 0;
  previousIndex = 0;
  previousRegion = 'world';
  displayMode = 'regions';
  resolution = resolutionArray[resolutionIndex];
  region = 'world';
  height = '600';
  width = '800';
}
```

Now the issue with this code is that I have to set all these variables inside the "options" variable as global, and I'm not quite sure that updating the variables like `resolution` inside the `resetMap()` function will actually affect the values inside options (would I need to create another function to update the `options` variable afterwards?). Also everything seems to be global, and I'm not sure how I can pass variables back and forth and make sure that they all work together to get the job done.

I know this is an incredibly long post with probably an exceedingly simple concept that would solve it for me, but I just can't wrap my head around it. If anyone has any general pointers, or a description of how functions work in javascript written for true beginners (how functions work, how they are defined, how to return values from them, etc.) I would be very grateful.

Comment: You probably want all your data in objects and then you pass a reference to an object around and you can read/write the data in the object.

Comment: Could you please expand on that? Imagine you are talking to someone who's most advanced formal training was in BASIC. Because you are. What is the process of actually doing that, and what's the concept behind it? I know my `options` variable is an object, and I can alter things in the object, but if I pass the object, do I pass all variables in it too? Or am I totally out in left field here?

Comment: There isn't a short answer to your question about how to write well-structured javascript without keeping state in global variables.  I'd suggest a good book on javascript.  The more specific part of your question is that you create an object and add properties to it and when you pass the object around, all the properties go with it.

Comment: Okay, I'm reading up on objects now [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp). It looks like I can create an `options` object (and it already is one in my code it would seem?) with functions in it to change the region, or change the resolution with something like `options.resolution(i)` rather than changing a variable and sending the object through, etc. So as long as I define the functions I want to do to the object, I can just keep fiddling with the object in a single function. Is this more-or-less on target? Anywhere else I should look?

Comment: Ugh, no, I definitely don't get it. If I create an options object, that's cool and all, but it's defined globally, no? Isn't that just the same as having a global variable? Clearly I have totally missed the point of Object Oriented Programming. Is it that bad just to define everything globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are worried about having global variables (that's good!) without knowing exactly why (that's bad!). The major problem with them is, nowadays it's very common to combine scripts from various sources in a web page. If all of them use global variables, the chances one will interfere (and break) another one because of naming collisions is high. So the best practice is to avoid globals.

To do that, the first thing you have to understand is [how scope works in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). Every function creates a new scope, so a `var` declared inside a function is only visible there. It's also visible inside nested functions (via [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)). Understanding those two concepts is essential if you want to avoid global variables.

There is also a simple language feature that may help you: an "immediately invoked function expression" (IIFE) can be used to wrap a block of code in its own scope. That scope can be used instead of the global scope to share variables with inner functions, which can access them via closures:

```
(function(){
    // declare common variables here
    var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

    // any function declare here can access a, b, c
    function foo() {
        console.log(a);
    }

    // works with anynymous function expressions too
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert(b);
    });
}());
```

That allows you to have code very similar to what you already have, but without leaking any globals.

Using [object-oriented js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) can also help you structure your code, but it's kind of a broad topic, and I can't get into any details here unless you ask about more specific issues you have with it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you thank you thank you! I can declare functions inside of functions, and the nested functions can all inherit the parent functions' variables! This means I can separate out my code logically by function, but not have to deal with as much of this crazy variable passing stuff. Boy that makes much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You might find the [Code Organization](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/) page on jQuery Learning interesting. Most of the concepts still apply even if you aren't using jQuery.

Comment: No offense, but this is the opening paragraph:  `When you move beyond adding simple enhancements to your website with jQuery and start developing full-blown client-side applications, you need to consider how to organize your code. In this chapter, we'll take a look at various code organization patterns you can use in your jQuery application and explore the RequireJS dependency management and build system.` Does that match what I'm asking for at all, or even seem in the same time zone as the level of answer I'm requesting? I can use google, I cannot decode jargon I don't know.

Comment: (that may have come across overly harsh, and if so I do apologize -- I can't understand the concepts if I don't understand the jargon, and the issue is that I seem to not understand the concepts of objects properly at all)